# JS templating in google chrome extension(manifest v2)

Tags: javascript, templates, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

With google chrome manifest 2.0, my template engine on javascript doesn't work.
I've used Jquery Template, and now can't upgrade manifest, beacause *new Function* and *eval* deprecated.

Is the any way to use templates with manifest 2.0, or only one way it's create dom objects in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the extension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/sandboxingEval.html) relating to sandboxing `eval`. There's even an [example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#sandboxed-frame) (may take a while to load) of how to do this with the Handlebars templating library.

In brief, you run the template engine within a sandboxed iframe, then use [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to transfer the results back to your extension.

Comment: Thanks. I found soulutions with sanbox earlier, but that look crazy.